# Visual Studio 2015 - Copy solution to new solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a **Visual Studio 2015** solution named **canaia** that contains a WebApi project named **dedio** .

Now I need to copy the solution to another different folder and I need to change the name of the solution and the name of the webapi project.

The new names I need are:

solution: **ficamarsa**

project: **tancule**

What are the properly steps to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried to do that at Visual Studio 2017, and here's sth that works for me ("John" is old solution name):

1. project / Build_Clean solution/save all, close solution
2. Copy to other directory
3. Open  solution from the new directory
4. Rename solution and project in solution explorer
5. Rebuild Solution
6. Build_Clean Solution
7. Save all, close solution
8. Manually edit .sln file changing solution names inside for ex:(= "John", "John\John.vcxproj")
9. Manually change name of the solution path and that inside .xproj files too
10. Manually change name of all three .xproj files names there
11. Open solution, rebuild, run
12. If ok then rename your namespace to the new solution name, do not forget to replace any reference to it (ex in the main() )
13. Build Clean, save, close
14. Open .vcxproj file end rename as above (in my case that was the line as below John)
15. Open

Hope it helps.